# Creating stl vector from pair of iterator c++

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I am trying to create a stl vector from iterator pair and I am not sure how many elements the vector might have. It could have only one element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<int> vect;
    for (int nCount=0; nCount < 6; nCount++)
        vect.push_back(nCount);

    vector<int> second(vect.begin(), vect.begin() );

    vector<int>::iterator it; // declare an read-only iterator
    it = second.begin(); // assign it to the start of the vector

    while (it != second.end()) // while it hasn't reach the end
    {
        cout << *it << " "; // print the value of the element it points to
        it++; // and iterate to the next element
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

I thought that vector 'second' would have one element pointed by vect.begin(). Is it not the case?

Thanks

Comment: You insert 0 elements...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vector<int> second(vect.begin(), vect.begin() + 1);
```

The vector constructor uses an open interval so the end is not included ie. `[first, last)`

As lip pointed out in his comment it's more generic to `next`:

```
second(vect.begin(), next(vect.begin()));
```

Comment: + 1 is only available because this is a vector. A more generic syntax would be `vector<int> second(vect.begin(), next(vect.begin()));`

Comment: I tried doing "vector<int> second;
    std::copy(vect.begin(), vect.begin(), std::back_inserter(second.begin()));" but I am not sure if this works. The problem is I am copying elemnts from another vector and there might be only one element in it pointed by begin()

Comment: @polapts: `next(vect.begin()) == vect.end()` so it's okay to use the method I posted.

Comment: If there are more than one elements to add then do I have to use an if condition like if(std::distance(itBegin, itEnd) >1) then second(vect.begin(), vect.end()); else second(vect.begin(), next(vect.begin()));?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not the case.  The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is pretty clear:

```
template< class InputIt > 
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); (4)
```

> 4) Constructs the container with the contents of the range [first,
>   last).

The notation "[first, last)" indicates that all the elements between `first` and `last` but not including `last` are copied.  Since `first` == `last`, no elements are copied.

Reading the documentation further, it would appear that you can use another constructor:

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());  (until C++11)
         vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());  (since C++11)
```

...in this way:

```
vector<int> second(1, vect.front());
```

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer with proper explanation. The interval is right-closed. This ability allows us to express an empty range. For more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Excluding_the_endpoints

Answer (score 2):

No. In the constructor `vector<int> second(vect.begin(), vect.begin());` the second iterator should point *past* the end, so you get exactly empty array.

Example: `vect.end()` points exactly *past the end* of vector `vect`, so `vector<int> second(vect.begin(), vect.end());` would copy the whole `vect` into `second`.