# cython create vector from iterators

Tags: c++, vector, cython

I see that it is possible to create a vector from iterators in c++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427943/creating-stl-vector-from-pair-of-iterator-c)
, however I see that this line is commented in the pxd files *vector.pxd*:

```
#vector[InputIt](InputIt, InputIt)
```

Any idea how to correct this to actually make it work? I tried uncommenting it obviously but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is still some shortcomings in Cython, which prevents one from defining a constructor with templates (this is possible though with usual methods, see e.g. [`assign`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd#L129) ).

However, when your variable is on stack, Cython doesn't let you use other constructors than the default-constructor anyway (as @DavidW has pointed out, there is [`cpp_locals`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#cpp-locals-directive) in Cython3.0 which would improve this situation), so the following workaround would be used anyway:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector as cvector
...
cdef cvector[int] b
b.assign(it_begin, it_end)
```

the situation is slightly more complicated if the object should be constructed on the heap via operator `new`. The simplest way is to write a wrapper like the following:

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp.vector cimport vector as cvector

cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <vector>
    template <typename T, typename It>
    std::vector<T>* create_vector(const It& begin, const It& end){
        return new std::vector<T>(begin, end);
    }
    """
    cvector[T]* create_vector[T, It](const It& begin, const It& end)

...
cdef cvector[int]* b = create_vector[int, cvector[int].iterator](it_begin, it_end)

# don't forget to manage the memory of b
```

Obviously, cython/c++ cannot deduce the value of the template parameter `T` (which should be int) and we need to specialize both, which is somewhat clumsy. If `create_vector` should be uses only with `int`s one could drop the template-parameter `T` completely which would lead to a code which is easier on the eyes:

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp.vector cimport vector as cvector


cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <vector>
    template <typename It>
    std::vector<int>* create_vector(const It& begin, const It& end){
        return new std::vector<int>(begin, end);
    }
    """
    cvector[int]* create_vector[It](const It& begin, const It& end)

...

cdef cvector[int]* b = create_vector(a.begin(), a.begin()+1)
```

Comment: "However, when your variable is on stack, Cython doesn't let you use other constructors than the default-constructor anyway, " - the `cpp_locals` directive wraps then in `std::optional` so they're initialized much more like Python variables. But is a fairly new addition

Comment: @DavidW thanks for the information! I probably should slowly be switching to Cython3.0 otherwise it will be a steep learning curve once it is released...